# Sharing text via Intent gets truncated on Whatsapp

Tags: android-intent, share

I am sharing some text via intent such that user can send to any app of their choose which is generated with `createChooser`
However, i realized that Text received by Whatsapp gets truncated when text size is large (1000 char or more), however full text is received on Email and other apps.
The only solution i found only permits sending solely to whatsApp `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`.

```
Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse("whatsapp://send?text="+text+""); 
Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);  
startActivity(launchBrowser);
```

Thats not what i want as i still want the choice of apps to be generated. What do i do?

```
   Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        shareIntent.putExtra("Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "TEXT");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "SUBJECT");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share..."));
```

Comment: Find on your code where is the explicit mention to whatsapp package. Comment out this line and runs. You then will be able to choose apps to share.

Comment: my text to be shared on whatsapp gets truncated when i do this.